# PHP mailer works in localhost but shows the following error in server

Tags: php, phpmailer

[image: PHPmailer error on my website]

I tried all the solutions given to questions similar to mine (allowed less secured apps, display captcha, using 465 port for ssl, etc).

Can anyone tell if I have to change any settings on cpanel to send mails using gmail?

Comment: your usernames/passwords seem to be wrong. the error message states this clear

Comment: @PhilippSander my code works on localhost but when i upload it to the server its showing this error. I have double checked username and password  again

Answer (score 0):

I remove below line from localhost code and it worked.

```
define("MAILER", "smtp");
```

Above line is not required and causing the error